# How can I make a line break on HostMath

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I want to express the following:

[image]

I need to express it on [HostMath](http://www.hostmath.com), where `\nextline` somehow doesn't work.

What I have so far:

```
\text(If ) \frac{x-3}{3}=k \text( and ) k=3, \text(what is the value of x?) 
\text{ A)2}\text{ B)4}\text{ C)9}\text{ D)10}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. In standard LaTeX document this is simple task: you combine ordinary text, in-line math and itemize environment.

Comment: Is Hostmath on-topic here? I think not, it is like mathML, I think ...

Comment: The site offers single equation processing, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you're working with a limited set of TeX functionality known as MathJax. Specifically you're forced to use a math environment, within which the following setup works:

[image]

```
\begin{array}{l}
  \text{If $\dfrac{x-3}{3} = k$ and $k = 3$, what is the value of $x$?} \\
  \text{A) 2} \\
  \text{B) 4} \\
  \text{C) 9} \\
  \text{D) 10}
\end{array}
```

Comment: Which makes the question off-topic